# Filtering pulses by width

Tags: filters

Assume we are receiving gaussian pulses and I'd like to do some sort of band-pass filter on the standard deviation $\sigma$ - as best as can be done. Is there a way to do this?

I have looked on google, and there are several mentions of [gaussian wavelet filters](https://www.google.com/search?q=gaussian%20wavelet%20filters&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS766US766&oq=gaussian%20wavelet%20filters&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), but I don't think these are what I'm looking for.

Comment: what $\sigma$ ranges are you looking for, i.e. what's the ratio between smallest and largest std.-dev. that you care about (a single impulse can be interpreted as Gaussian with zero deviation, and a constant as one with infinite deviation, and you definitely only care about things in between).

Comment: I could start with 3 ranges of  std deviation based on some baseline $\sigma$: $1\sigma$, $2\sigma$, $4 \sigma$